# Redux: Generic Reducer vs Reducer per Entity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux, state

When using Redux, which is generally better practice: To implement *entity specific reducers* or to implement *generic reducer* based on strict action keying conventions? Former solution has a lot of boilerplate code but is loosely coupled and more flexible. Latter solution has less of boilerplate but is more fragile and restrictive.

As our domain has dozens of entities, I initially leaned towards latter solution. I designed generic entity reducer which utilizes JavaScript computed property names to manipulate the state according to dispatched action types. It's all dynamic and convention based.

At first the solution worked well, until I realized there's a structural mismatch among different entity resources in some use cases. Some endpoints returns a collection, where as some returns a singe result and so on. Thus I had to decompose the generic reducer to adapt to different use cases. I started adding snippets of conditional logic here and there. And eventually found myself lost and confused! Now I have hard time getting things back in order. Architecturally lucid vision actually ended up as hard to maintain big ball of mud very quickly.

Should I just give up with generic solution and refactor the store to use entity specific reducers regardless of boilerplate? Has someone actually implemented and maintained generic reducer logic for complex Admin GUI application successfully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redux - One vs Multiple reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777227/redux-one-vs-multiple-reducers)

Answer (score 1):

> At first the solution worked well, until I realized there's a
>   structural mismatch among different entity resources in some use
>   cases. Some endpoints returns a collection, where as some returns a
>   singe result and so on. Thus I had to decompose the generic reducer to
>   adapt to different use cases.

As you have correctly pointed out that generic solution get very complex very quickly with lot of conditionals and subsequent state modification.

Having a generic reducer is okay if we have small static website with certain actions.

But if you have dynamic website with huge number of entities or nested entities(scary), shape of the state can get very complex. In my opinion, handing that kind of shape in 1 reducer is not a prudent approach.

Having modular reducers also completely decouples multiple action dispatches and state changes that may happen with single action of the user.

[@Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399317/kos) wrote a fabulous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777227/redux-one-vs-multiple-reducers) which you may want to read.